# SQL - What does "min(row) row" do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, min

How does the following query work?

```
select i601_ID, min(row) row from SortPlaetzeDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to `SELECT i601_ID, MIN(row) AS row FROM SortPlaetzeDate`. It assigns the name "row" to the second column. "AS" is optional.